# How can i display footer depending on the language website?PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the code I tried but unfortunately does not work

```
          <?php if(get_the_ID()==22) : ?>



          <p class="dg-design"> website by <a href="http://www.dg-design.ch" target="blank"> dgdesign </a></p></p>



                       elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='es'){

                                 <p class="dg-design"> websadsasite by <a href="http://www.dg-design.ch" target="blank"> dgdessadsadaign </a></p></p>

                               }


          <?php endif; ?>
```

Can you tell me what is wrong please?
At the moment when I run the site does not change anything
I use a wordpress theme.

Can you give an example to show me how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not reopening the PHP tag for the second conditional, you're using inconsistent syntax (braces vs semicolon), your conditions are dubious (it seems to me) and you probably should use a proper template system for this. I feel you don't describe the context (is `get_the_ID() == 22` really the English case or are you missing a conditional?) nor the actual result adequately enough ("does not change anything" compared to what?). I believe that even though SO might be able to help you fix a few issues like this, ultimately you'll need to learn some fundamentals on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(is_page(22)){?>
        <?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){?>
    <p class="dg-design"> website by 
        <a href="http://www.dg-design.ch" target="blank"> dgdesign </a>
    </p>
       <?php }elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='es'){?>
    <p class="dg-design"> websadsasite by 
       <a href="http://www.dg-design.ch" target="blank"> dgdessadsadaign </a></p>
       <?php }?>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Well your code is only supposed to run on the page with the id of 22. I have seen your edited code, but you are still missing an if condition. Just replace all this with my new code. And what plugin are you using for the translation?

Comment: WMPL use for translation.
I put the new code but still does not work ... very strange

Comment: Are you checking it on page id 22?

Comment: well its working on your website, check the page id of 22 thats contact page

Comment: i checked on your website and its working fine. If you want to show it on all pages just remove the first and the last line of my code

Comment: OK i now understand where you are confused. You have 2 different contact pages. One for english with id of 22 and one for espaniol with the id of 559. So you have to add an OR statement in php and check for both. Replace the first line with <?php if(is_page(22) || is_page(559)){?>